Simple while loop outputting unexpected values (beginner)
Learning c++, wrote a simple while loop for practice and when I run the program, the increment is not consistent for each iteration. After printing 0.83, the next printed increment is 0.839999 rather than 0.84.
This is the while loop I made:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float f1 = 0.00;
    float f2 = 1.00;

    while (f2 > f1)
    {
        cout << f1 << endl;
        f1 += .01;
    }
    system("pause");
}

This is the problematic part of the output I see when I run the program (all previous increments are correct):
0.83
0.839999
0.849999
0.859999
0.869999
0.879999
0.889999
0.899999
0.909999
0.919999
0.929999
0.939999
0.949999
0.959999
0.969999
0.979999
0.989999
0.999999


Most real-world floating point types have a base-2 significand.   Once consequence of this is that they CANNOT exactly represent values like 0.1 or 0.01 - the best they can do is represent an approximation.     The reason is the same that one-third cannot be represented exactly using a finite number of decimal places, except (for base 2 places) different values are affected (and 0.1 and 0.01 are both affected with a base-2).   So there is an error introduced, and doing multiple operations (adding such a value repeatedly) propagates the error

See also: Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate? and Floating point comparison a != 0.7

The correct way to do this is to multiply everything by 100.0 and then divide by 100.0 when you output the values. I.e. float f1 = 0.0; float f2 = 100.0; while (f2 > f1) { cout << f1/100.0 << endl; f1 += 1.0; } This avoids the inaccuracies introduced by using 0.01. Also in C++ generally use double instead of float, double is typically faster and more accurate.

Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile is a lightweight video by Tom Scott explaining the problem in a fun way,

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.
